# Как отследить изменение атрибута value у тега input?

Tags: javascript, dom

Как сделать чтобы при изменении атрибута value у тега input выполнялась функция changed?

```js
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.value = 'prevValue';
document.body.append(input)


function changed() {
    console.log('changed')
}

document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value = 'nextValue'
```

Answer (score 0):

Довольно просто

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="login"/>
</form>
<script>
    const input = document.querySelector("input[name=login]");
    input.onchange = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        console.log(value);
    };
</script>
```